# Integral relation on Lie (Super)algebra

Tags: operators, path-integral, supersymmetry, lie-algebra, matrix-model

I have the following integral relation where $X$ is an element of a Lie (super)algebra, $Y_i$ are functions on the respective Lie group and $M$ is an element of the Lie group:

$$Y_1(M)=\int{D}Xe^{-\frac{1}{t}\text{STr}{X^2}}Y_0(Me^X).$$

$t$ is a parameter and the measure $DX$ fulfills $$\int{DX}e^{-\frac{1}{t}\text{STr}X^2}=1$$ for all $t>0$. Now for $t$ small the exponential containing $\frac{1}{t}$ behaves more and more like a $\delta$ function. I want to compute the 'deviation' from a $\delta$ function by expressing the equation for $Y_1(M)$ as a sum of $Y_0(M)$ and a second order differential operator. The first step should be to write $Y_0(Me^X)$ as a Taylor expansion which I think yields $$Y_0(M)+(L_X.Y_0)(M)+\frac{1}{2}(L_X^2.Y_0)(M)+...$$ where $L_X$ is the left invariant vector field associated to $X$. Now one gets

$$Y_1(M)=Y_0(M)+\int{DX}e^{-\frac{1}{t}\text{STr}X^2}\big((L_X.Y_0)(M)+\frac{1}{2}(L_X^2.Y_0)(M)+...\big)$$

Now my problem: In this form one has differential operators acting on $Y_0$ but there is still the integral over the Lie algebra elements which I don't know how to evaluate. My feeling is that the first order should vanish due to the integral being of Gauss-type and the second order yields a generalized Laplace operator but I don't know how to prove these statements.

I would be very grateful for a little hint how to proceed from here.

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?

Comment: No there is no reference. It's a calculation I want to perform but unfortunately I don't know much about the Lie Superalgebra only that the matrices $X$ are 2x2 graded matrices. I hoped that the calculation works quite generally by using how the left invariant vector field act on functions on the Lie group. But here I am stuck unfortunately. I would suppose that the calculation or the result is somehow similar to Kramers Moyal expansion (an adaption of Kramers Moyal expansion to Lie Groups).